# XPath Select Nodes where all parent nodes do not contain specific attribute and value

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML structure:

```
<root>
  <Level1 IsEnabled="0"> <!-- Disabled -->
    <Level2 IsEnabled="1">
      <Level3 IsEnabled="1">
        <Level4 IsEnabled="1">
          <Child /> <!-- Don't include this one -->
        </Level4>
      </Level3>
    </Level2>
  </Level1>
  <Level1 IsEnabled="1">
    <Level2 IsEnabled="1">
      <Level3 IsEnabled="0"> <!-- Disabled -->
        <Level4 IsEnabled="1">
          <Child /> <!-- Don't include this one -->
        </Level4>
      </Level3>
    </Level2>
  </Level1>
  <Level1 IsEnabled="1">
    <Level2 IsEnabled="1">
      <Level3 IsEnabled="1">
        <Level4 IsEnabled="1">
          <Child /><!-- Include this one -->
        </Level4>
      </Level3>
    </Level2>
   </Level1>
</root>
```

I want to select all child nodes where any of its ancestors do not contain IsEnabled="0".  So for the XML above I only want to select the last child node.  In addition, if a ancestor node doesn't contain a IsEnabled attribute, then the child should still be included.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Q: *I want to select all child nodes where any of its ancestors do not contain IsEnabled="0"*
Try this:

```
//Child[not(ancestor::*[@IsEnabled='0'])]
```

Comment: was about to post the same 2 seconds later :)

Comment: Ah!  Nice!  I was trying //Child[ancestor::*[not(@IsEnabled='0')]] - just needed to move the not.  Thank you!

Comment: This is brilliant, I didn't know how to do that!